# Unable to position overlay form to center of parent

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Actually i'm trying to show a overlay form and a Dialog in my winForm programm but the issue is that when overlay form is called and even if StartPosition is set to CenterParent it show that form in another position instead of parent form.

Actually the form is called from a click method and here is how i'm calling it.

```
                DialogOverlay.Show() 'Overlay Form opacity 60%
                Dim dr As DialogResult = DialogSuccess.ShowDialog 'Actual Dialog Alert
                If dr = DialogResult.Abort Then
                    DialogOverlay.Close()
                End If
```

[image]

Comment: try DialogOverlay.Showdialog() instead of show() it might show the overlay form from main form thread and the center parent might work

Comment: you can always set the position of overlay form programmatically, use DialogOverlay.shown event and set the position to somewhere related to main form

Comment: @Devcon actually by calling ShowDialog() both on DialogOverlay and DialogSuccess only DialogOverlay is shown..

Comment: It's because DialogSuccess should be called from DialogOverlay not from main form, call it from DialogOverlay and they will all show

Comment: @Devcon even if i call it onLoad of DialogOverlay it will show just DialogSuccess and when i'll close it it will show DialogOverlay

Comment: try it onShown instead of onLoad

Comment: @Devcon oh yeah that was it, make an answer so i'd accept it

Comment: done, glad i could help

Comment: The overlay does not have a parent, so CenterParent cannot work.  Easy to fix, use the Show(owner) overload.  The snippet is too brief, but probably just `DialogOverlay.Show(this);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DialogOverlay.Showdialog() instead of show(), DialogSuccess should be called from DialogOverlay onShown event